# Android activity finished drawing

Tags: android, android-activity, screenshot

I'd like to take a screenshot as soon as the activity finishes drawing its layout.
To take the screenshot I am using the rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); and getDrawingCache.
My problem is that if the activity hasn't finished loading, that doesn't work.

I tried creating a thread that waits until getDrawingCache isn't null. But that's just aweful code, and crashes pretty often. Is there anyway to know when did an activity finish drawing its layout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding Activity's method :

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)

The activity should be finished drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `onDraw()` of your root view. Place the code after `super.onDraw()`.

Comment: Hi thank you, I found a solution using AsyncTask. Using the onPostExecute method. Here's more information if anyone needs in the future: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: It didn't work, even with asynctask, it isn't loaded yet. Sometimes bitmaps returned by getDrawingCache are still null. I can't use onDraw, because the way I am doing I am accessing the rootview by View.getRootView(), I am not using my root view.. I am using the decorview from activity. Any other ideas?